# WPF DataGrid RowDetails - bind inner DataGrid to parent DataRow of outer DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgOuter" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID.oldValue}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name.oldValue}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender.oldValue}" />
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>            
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID.newValue}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name.newValue}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender.newValue}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The outer DataGrid's DataContext is a list of Objects containing ID, Name and Gender as properties. These are again Objects containing an oldValue and newValue.

Goal: RowDetails shall exactly display the same row as selected, however showing newValue instead of oldValue.

Problem: I do not know how to point to the DataBound item of the selected row.

I already achieved this using TextBoxes instead of a new inner DataGrid, but this is really a lot of code.

What's the correct binding for the inner DataGrid?

Comment: Outer grid would show some values in the row. If we edit the row, it will contain new values, and now if click that row to see detailed view, detailed view should show the old values that were present. Is that what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner DataGrid's Bindings don't work, because ItemSource is supposed to be bound to a Collection. You can use a Converter to wrap the SelectedItem in a Collection (for example a list).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:ToCollectionConverter x:Key="ToCollectionConverter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID.newValue}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name.newValue}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender.newValue}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ToCollectionConverter}}"     
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      HeadersVisibility="None"
                      >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID.oldValue}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name.oldValue}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender.oldValue}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Working perfectly.

One emphasis just in case: Using <DataGrid.Columns> is really important. Without, an XamlParseException is thrown. I just ran into this issue by accident.